# How to set jetty.xml fragment bundle property in Karaf

Tags: jetty, apache-karaf, karaf, pax-web

I created a fragment host for `org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty` which contains a jetty.xml file which is perfectly picked up inside Karaf.

This jetty.xml file contains a line like this:

```
<Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.ssl.host" deprecated="jetty.host" /></Set>
```

Could you tell me where to set `jetty.ssl.host` so that I can set a value please ?

Best,
Jerome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik, it's not possible in the current version of pax-web.

In the [source](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/blob/master/pax-web-jetty/src/main/java/org/ops4j/pax/web/service/jetty/internal/JettyServerImpl.java#L147), the `XmlConfiguration` doesn't have any property set :

```
XmlConfiguration configuration = new XmlConfiguration(jettyResource);
// configuration.configure(m_server);
Method method = XmlConfiguration.class.getMethod("configure", Object.class);
method.invoke(configuration, server);
```

This kind of property (`<Property ../>`) is normally set using the `XmlConfiguration.getProperties()` method, which isn't used here.

You should probably use another way to provide an external configuration (like `systemProperty` for example, or creating your own bean in this jetty.xml file).